# SQL alchemy geoalchemy selecting geometry array

Tags: python, postgresql, geoalchemy2

I've created irregular geometry table which contains point array as geometry type column and I'm trying to retrieve points as per measurement point id.

But I'm having an error :

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce) cannot cast type geometry[] to geometry
> LINE 1: SELECT ST_X(CAST(db.irregular.axises AS geometry(GEOMETR...

This is how it is in database:

```
     column_name      | data_type | numeric_scale || udt_schema | udt_name  | 
----------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+------------+
 id                   | integer   |             0 | | pg_catalog | int4      |
 measurement_point_id | integer   |             0 | | pg_catalog | int4      |
 axises               | ARRAY     |               | | public     | _geometry |
```

This is my irregular table class:

```
#%% Irregular Class
class Irregular (object):
    measurement_point_id = relationship("measurement_points", back_populates="id")

    def __init__(self,measurement_point_id,axises=None,id= None):
        self.id = id
        self.measurement_point_id = measurement_point_id
        self.axises = axises
        #self.is_xy = xy

#Irregular Object
__tablename__ = 'irregular'
irregular = Table(
    __tablename__,meta,
    Column ('id', Integer, primary_key = True), 
    Column ( 'measurement_point_id',Integer,ForeignKey('measurement_points.id')),
    Column ( 'axises', ARRAY(Geometry('POINT'))),
    #Column ( 'is_xy', Boolean),
)
mapper(Irregular, irregular)
```

This is how I am trying to get data :

```
session.query(fns.ST_X(cast(tb.Irregular.axises, geoalchemy2.types.Geometry)),\
                             fns.ST_Y(cast(tb.Irregular.axises, geoalchemy2.types.Geometry)).filter(tb.measurement_point_id == id).all()
```

I removed casting :
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function st_x(geometry[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_X(db.irregular.axises) AS "ST_X_1", ST_Y(db...

I think I need to retrieve as tuple array but I couldn't find how to cast from python side and which function should I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this with

```
session.query(fns.ST_AsGeoJSON(fns.ST_Collect(tb.Irregular.axises)))
.filter(tb.Irregular.measurement_point_id == mpoint_id)
.first()[0]
```